# Maven can't resolve dependencies

Tags: maven

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project accord-web-utils: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.accord.web:accord-web-utils:jar:1.0.4-SNAPSHOT: 
Could not find artifact com.accord.business.bafr:accord-business-bafr:jar:1.0.5-SNAPSHOT in snapshots (http://sv0311:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot) ->
```

I am getting the above error when I updated the version of `com.accord.business.bafr:accord-business-bafr`. How can I resolve it?

Comment: can you post your dependency artifact?

Comment: Above dependency does not exist on maven. You can check it here: http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=accord&p=1

Comment: accord web is the name of the project

Comment: so does it exists in `http://sv0311:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot` ?  Or do you mean `com.accord.business.bafr:accord-business-bafr` is part of a multi-module project that you are currently building and you have supposedly update all version of all modules to 1.0.5-SNAPSHOT?  Tell us clearly what you have done and what's the problem.  If not, it is just like you are declaring a non-existed dependency and of course that will fail

Comment: I am new to maven i dont know how to check http://sv0311:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot. bafr is another project(yes, you can say a part of multi-module project) whose dependency i am adding to accord-web-utils

Comment: how can i add my dependency to this path?

Comment: if it's an internal jar : you have to install it manually like [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) and then declare it in you pom.xml